# Firefox lose focus on the nested textbox

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a nested textbox inside a radiobuttom list item
here is the code

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="OtherEducInNursing" runat="server" RepeatColumns="1" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Table">
            <asp:ListItem Value="1">Certificate<input id="OtherEdNsgCertName" type="text" MaxLength="25"/></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2">Baccalaureate</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="3">Master</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="4">Doctorate</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="5">None of the above</asp:ListItem></asp:RadioButtonList>
```

It works fine both in chrome, but in firefox, when i tried to click the textbox, the blinking cursor loses focus, I have to click the text box couple times to get cursor back

I added some code like this

```
 onclick="document.getElementById('OtherEdNsgCertName').focus();"
```

which still didn't work, doesn anyone know why and how to fix it? thanks very much

edit
here is the jquery code too

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if($("#<%=OtherEducInNursing.ClientID%> :checked").val()!="1")
            $("#OtherEdNsgCertName").hide();
        else
            $("#OtherEdNsgCertName").show();
    $("#<%=OtherEducInNursing.ClientID%>").click(function () {
        if($("#<%=OtherEducInNursing.ClientID%> :checked").val()!="1")
            $("#OtherEdNsgCertName").hide();
        else
            $("#OtherEdNsgCertName").show();
    });
```

edit：
html code:

```
<table id="MainPlaceHolder_OtherEducation_OtherEducInNursing">
<tbody><tr>
    <td><input type="radio" value="1" name="ctl00$MainPlaceHolder$OtherEducation$OtherEducInNursing" id="MainPlaceHolder_OtherEducation_OtherEducInNursing_0"><label for="MainPlaceHolder_OtherEducation_OtherEducInNursing_0">Certificate<input type="text" onclick="document.getElementById('OtherEdNsgCertName').focus();" maxlength="25" id="OtherEdNsgCertName"></label></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><input type="radio" value="2" name="ctl00$MainPlaceHolder$OtherEducation$OtherEducInNursing" id="MainPlaceHolder_OtherEducation_OtherEducInNursing_1"><label for="MainPlaceHolder_OtherEducation_OtherEducInNursing_1">Baccalaureate</label></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><input type="radio" value="3" name="ctl00$MainPlaceHolder$OtherEducation$OtherEducInNursing" id="MainPlaceHolder_OtherEducation_OtherEducInNursing_2"><label for="MainPlaceHolder_OtherEducation_OtherEducInNursing_2">Master</label></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><input type="radio" value="4" name="ctl00$MainPlaceHolder$OtherEducation$OtherEducInNursing" id="MainPlaceHolder_OtherEducation_OtherEducInNursing_3"><label for="MainPlaceHolder_OtherEducation_OtherEducInNursing_3">Doctorate</label></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><input type="radio" value="5" name="ctl00$MainPlaceHolder$OtherEducation$OtherEducInNursing" id="MainPlaceHolder_OtherEducation_OtherEducInNursing_4"><label for="MainPlaceHolder_OtherEducation_OtherEducInNursing_4">None of the above</label></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It would be easier to see what was going on if you showed us HTML and JavaScript instead of ASP that will generate HTML and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the focus function from the textbox and give focus in your jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if($("#<%=OtherEducInNursing.ClientID%> :checked").val()!="1")
        $("#OtherEdNsgCertName").hide();
    else
        {
            $("#OtherEdNsgCertName").show();
            $("#OtherEdNsgCertName").focus();
        }
$("#<%=OtherEducInNursing.ClientID%>").click(function () {
    if($("#<%=OtherEducInNursing.ClientID%> :checked").val()!="1")
        $("#OtherEdNsgCertName").hide();
    else
        {
            $("#OtherEdNsgCertName").show();
            $("#OtherEdNsgCertName").focus();
        }

});
```

Comment: By the way shorter version would `$("#OtherEdNsgCertName").show().focus();`

Comment: do you know why this only happened in firefox?

Comment: After reading the documentation on jQuery.show() I am really not sure. So I don;t have an answer sorry.